# Android webview save html and js for later use

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a html5 game and I want to make it available to play on android device.
So far I have a webview which is loading the game.
The problem is that the users will need internet connection everytime when they want to play it.

How can I save all the html,js,images etc. in the app and make the webview load them from the phone storrage !?

Comment: Hello @user5207705 was wondering if you got solution for above?